# Como Criar um histórico de navegação Para Navegador Android? -Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, navegador-de-internet

Olá eu estou criando um navegador para Android com webview usando Android Studio ele já faz pesquisa agora estou querendo fazer um histórico de navegação onde fica os sites que foram entrados, igual só Google Chrome, so que não faço a mínima ideia possível de como começar a fazer isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria você criar um banco Sqlite com uma tabela pra o histórico e salvar os dados, como a url, data de acesso etc e tal. Desta forma você pode exibi-la posteriormente e a pessoa pode acessar novamente os links pelo histórico :D

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda amigo.

Comment: Por nada mano :D